# How to fix "Not Found" html using Controller and Request Mapping in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

First of all I don't know if my question is the correct question to as so I'm just going to explain it. I'm new to Spring MVC and I'm trying an example where I will click on a text and redirect it to hello.html and try out the controller but for some reason even though I created the Controller with Request Mapping it won't work or it will not found the file.

Here is my controller **HelloWorldController** in the com.springapp.controllers package:

```html
package com.springapp.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController
{

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView hello()
    {
        String message = "Hajimemashite!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }

}
```

And in my **dispatcher-servlet.xml** I have a line of code:

```html
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.controllers" />
```

Here is my **index.jsp**

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Spring App Try</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="hello.html">Click Here</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

and in my **hello.jsp**

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ${message}
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know if I'm doing it properly. Can someone help me and enlighten me if I'm doing it wrong. So far I've tried replacing `@RequestMapping("/hello")` in my HelloWorldController with `@RequestMapping(value="/hello")` but when I tried clicking the "Click Here" the same result:

[Result When Clicking the "Click Here"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6biN.png)

I also tried replacing the hello.jsp to hello.html but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `http://localhost:8080/Spring_HelloWord_App/hello` you are trying `http://localhost:8080/Spring_HelloWord_App/hello.html` which is not mapped to any controller method.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @shazin you need to set the url to /hello instead of hello.html. See that it invokes your controller. You will also need to configure your view resolver to locate your hello.jsp file, after controller is invoked. Refer [ViewResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver)